# How is first tree in Boosting constructed

Tags: boosting

How is the first tree in GBM  constructed, and how the node splitting criteria for the first tree is decided. Can someone please explain, what we are predicting for the first tree (even assuming a constant is initialized for the target, how are gradient of loss computed from the constant) and if mse is the split criteria, what is it composed of (squared difference of what values??)

Answer (score 1):

An initial value is given to each sample **before** the first tree is fit.  How those values are determined differs a bit by implementation:

- [`sklearn`'s GBMs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) have an `init` parameter, which can be constant 0 or some other sklearn estimator.
- [`xgboost` has the parameter](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters) `base_score`, defaulting to 0.5 (?)
- `R`'s `gbm` is based on `C++`'s `gbm`, and has an initial value that depends on the loss function.  See section 4 of [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/vignettes/gbm.pdf).

After that, the loss is set and the gradient makes sense and the first tree being built is no different from any other.